# DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Estoy tratando de hacer web scraping, pero no hay forma de poder comenzar. He revisado ya algunas consultas muy parecidas en stackoverflow en inglés y español, pero ninguna soluciona mi problema.

Adjunto el brevísimo código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
    
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/mbuso/Desktop/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
```

Respuesta:

Aparece el siguiente aviso:

> ```
> <ipython-input-15-96eb42ae85c6>:4: DeprecationWarning: executable_path
> has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object  
> driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/mbuso/Desktop/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
> ```

Y el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   at block 8, line 4
> WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
> ```

No sé si estoy dejándome algún paso. Solamente he descargado el chromedriver, lo he puesto en una carpeta en mi escritorio y he puesto la ruta manualmente. ¿Y qué significa que el executable_path has been deprecated? ¿Obsoleto? Me dice esto de "please pass in a service object", pero no sé a qué se refiere.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda,

Un saludo.

Comment: debes usar un Service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719359/

Answer (score -1):

Te falta `executable_path`

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/mbuso/Desktop/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
```